# Align Text To Row Identified by Number and to ID Matching that Embedded in String

Tags: formula, spreadsheet

I need to align text in an ALERT STRING column with the row identified by number in an ID ROW column.

Additionally, I need to also align the same ALERT STRING text with the same ID ROW number AND with the ID matching that embedded in a string in the TEXT WITH ID column. (This double-check will sometimes be necessary with the real-world data.)

So far, I've only figured out how to align the ALERT STRING with the ID matching that embedded in the TEXT WITH ID column:
`=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(A2,$F$2:$F$11),$G$2:$G$11)`

I appreciate any help folks can offer. You can find an editable copy of the workbook here:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArQ7Kw6ayNMY2zktTW3pDCbMmJZ_

**UPDATE**: [Nayan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9871073/nayan) provided a solution to the first part of this question (please see answer below). I'm still trying to work out a formula for the column D part of this question, in which the row reference shown in column E is combined with a match of the ID shown in column A with its corresponding value in one of the text strings in column F.

The best I've been able to come up with so far is a formula with a high failure rate:
`=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(ROW(D2),$E$2:$E$11,MATCH("*"&A2&"*",$F$2:$F$11,0)))`

Any help with this part of the question will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Alert String to ID]

Comment: check updated formula in workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ROW([reference])

- Returns the row number of a reference
- E.g.: `Row(B2)` returns 2. If nothing provided like `ROW()` will also
  return row number based on position of cell where it is called.

> VLOOKUP(loolup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])

- Looks for a value in the leftmost column of a table, and then returns a value in the same row from a column you specify (col_index_num)
- By default - the table must be sorted in an ascending order.

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(ROW(B2),$E$2:$G$11,3,FALSE)
```

> INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num]) INDEX(reference, row_num,
> [column_num], [area_num])

- Returns a value or reference of the cell at the intersection of a particular row and column, in a given range.

In this case, you have to get row_num with MATCH function.

> MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])

- Returns a relative position of an item in an array that matches a specified value in a specified order.
- `match_type`: 1 (Less than), 0 (Exact match), -1 (Greater than)

Try this:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(ROW(B2),$E$2:$E$11,0))
```

Identity Data with Multiple Criteria Condition using `MATCH()`

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(1, (ROW(D2) = $E$2:$E$11) * (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2, $F$2:$F$11))),0))
```

References:

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-index-function

https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: Nayan: You offered an interesting formula, but for reasons I can't quite figure out it seems to return inconsistent results on some rows. For instance, the first result (B2) shows “Weasels Ripped My Flesh” but it should actually show “Cruising For Burgers.” Many of the other results are correct, though. I'm not sure why.

Comment: check updated answer and formula in workbook.

Comment: Your updated answer works on this test data, @Nayan; I very much appreciate this! I just up-voted your solution, and hope to test it on real-world data in the coming hours. I want to leave this question unresolved for now, however, in hopes that an answer for the other part of the question (a combined match for both the row number and embedded ID) will come along.

Comment: Nayan: Here's an INDEX MATCH version of your solution that also seems to work well (for folks who prefer INDEX MATCH over VLOOKUP):
`=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(ROW(B2),$E$2:$E$11,0))`
BTW: I had the chance to try your solution in real-world data; it seems to work well!

Comment: Glad to hear. Please mark as accept answer, so it will help others to find answers quickly.

Comment: Nayan: I am still trying to work out a solution for the 2nd part of my question (column D in the [ROWNUMTOROW](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArQ7Kw6ayNMY2zktTW3pDCbMmJZ_?e=fUatTb) worksheet). That's the component that evaluates both the row number and matches the ID in the ID column to the same ID embedded in a string in the “Alert String to ID Identified by ID ROW & ID Matching that Embedded in TEXT WITH ID” column.

So far, I have tried the formula shown below, which has a high failure rate, and is therefore useless.
`=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(ROW(D2),$E$2:$E$11,MATCH("*"&A2&"*",$F$2:$F$11,0)))`

Comment: updated answer. 
Try this: 
=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(1, (ROW(D2) = $E$2:$E$11) * (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2, $F$2:$F$11))),0))

Comment: I like your solution for column D, @Nayan! Thank you! (Of course, I also like your solution for column B as well.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula I was looking for in column D:

`=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(ROW(D2)&"*"&A2&"*",INDEX($E$2:$E$11&$F$2:$F$11,),0))`

You can see it working [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArQ7Kw6ayNMY2zktTW3pDCbMmJZ_?e=mgOBgY).

[Nayan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9871073/nayan) provided a great deal of help with answering this question, so I will mark his answer as the accepted solution.

[Syeda Fahima Nazreen](https://www.exceldemy.com/author/fahima/) provided the [example](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-index-match-multiple-criteria/#2_Nested_Excel_Formula_with_Two_INDEX_Functions_and_a_MATCH_Function_with_Multiple_Criteria) I referenced to figure out the formula shown above.

**Reference**:
[Nested Excel Formula with Two INDEX Functions and a MATCH Function with Multiple Criteria](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-index-match-multiple-criteria/#2_Nested_Excel_Formula_with_Two_INDEX_Functions_and_a_MATCH_Function_with_Multiple_Criteria)